# Real Representation of Hyperbolic matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I'm working on a take-home test and this is one of the questions:

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the hyperbolic numbers.
>
> A typical hyperbolic number has the form $a + bj$ where $a, b \in R$ and $j^2=1$.
>
> Form $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{H}^{2x2}$. This is an eight dimensional real algebra where $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$ have product $AB$ where $AB$ denotes the usual multiplication of $2×2$ matrices.
>
> Find the regular representation of $\mathcal{A}$ by $8 × 8$ real matrices.

I can, I believe, represent this using a $4x4$ matrix using the mapping

$\left[\matrix{a+bj & c+dj \\ e+fj & g+hj}\right] \Rightarrow \left[\matrix{a & b & c & d \\ b & a & d & c \\ e & f & g & h \\ f & e & h & g}\right]$

Trouble is, the teacher asks for the $8×8$ representation.  This is a test so I don't want an outright answer, but can anyone guide me in the right direction, or at least tell me what, if anything, is wrong with what I have?

Edit:
It appears that what he was looking for was the mapping

$\left[\matrix{a+bj & c+dj \\ e+fj & g+hj}\right] \Rightarrow \left[\matrix{a & b & 0 & 0 & c & d & 0 & 0 \\ b & a & 0 & 0 & d & c & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a & b & 0 & 0 & c & d \\ 0 & 0 & b & a & 0 & 0 & d & c \\ e & f & 0 & 0 & g & h & 0 & 0 \\ f & e & 0 & 0 & h & g & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e & f & 0 & 0 & g & h \\ 0 & 0 & f & e & 0 & 0 & h & g}\right]$

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that the $j$ here is different than the quaternion $j$.  Specifically, if I'm not mistaken, the $j$ in the quaternions has the property $j^2=-1$, while the $j$ here has the property $j^2=1$.

Comment: @Dieterian Thanks, I hadn't pay attention. I have already seen such numbers but I dont recall their name. One thing is sure: I have to erase my remarks...

Comment: I have found back the other name: these numbers are usually called "dual numbers".

Comment: Why do you think it's okay to ask for help on a test?